# Cannot update a component while rendering a different component To locate the bad setState() call inside `DeltaY`, follow the stack trace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, react-context

I have **react** project generated by **vite**, I get this error when I add **eventListener** to the DOM. I also use React context API. But I think there might be a problem with the StateProvider.jsx that contains the context API but I'm not sure.

**The error says:**

```
Cannot update a component (`StateProvider`) while rendering a different component (`DeltaY`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `DeltaY`, follow the stack trace as described in ...
```

**Here is the snapshot of the error in the console:**
[image]

**Here is the code:**

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { StateProvider } from './StateProvider.jsx';
import reducer, { initialState } from './reducer';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
    <App />
  </StateProvider>,
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import './App.css';
import DeltaY from './DeltaY';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <DeltaY />
      <Desc />
    </>
  );
}

const Desc = () => {
  const [{ deltaY, scrollMode }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  return (
    <>
      <h1> deltaY: {deltaY} </h1>
      <h1> scroll: {scrollMode} </h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**DeltaY.jsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';

const DeltaY = () => {
  // ------------------------------ context API ------------------------------- //
  const [{ state }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  // ------------------------------ context API ------------------------------- //

  const [scrollMode, setScrollMode] = useState(false);
  const [deltaY, setDeltaY] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleWheel(e) {
      setDeltaY(e.deltaY);
      setScrollMode(true);
    }
    window.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setScrollMode(true);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  // ------------------------------ dispatch ------------------------------- //
  dispatch({
    type: 'GET_DELTAY',
    value: deltaY,
  });

  dispatch({
    type: 'GET_SCROLLMODE',
    value: scrollMode,
  });
  // ------------------------------ dispatch ------------------------------- //

  return null;
};

export default DeltaY;
```

**StateProvider.jsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

// prepare the daya layer
export const StateContext = createContext();

// Wrap our app and provide the data layer
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
      </StateContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

// PUll the information from the data layer
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Any Idea how to fix it ? thankyou

Comment: Why are you calling `dispatch` unconditionally inside `DeltaY`?

Comment: Is `DeltaY` meant to be a custom hook, perhaps, rather than a component?

Comment: I use it to send some data to the reducer, ```   dispatch({
    type: 'GET_DELTAY',
    value: deltaY,
  });```  @Unmitigated

Comment: yes @Andy I think that's what might cause the error, I will try to use that as a custom hook

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
instead of using it as a component, I use it as a custom Hook

**Here is the code:**

**useDeltaY.jsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useDeltaY = () => {
  const [scrollMode, setScrollMode] = useState(false);
  const [deltaY, setDeltaY] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleWheel(e) {
      setDeltaY(e.deltaY);
      setScrollMode(true);
    }
    window.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setScrollMode(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, [scrollMode]);

  return [deltaY, scrollMode];
};

export default useDeltaY;
```

**App.jsx**

```
import './App.css';
import useDeltaY from './useDeltaY';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Desc />
    </>
  );
}

const Desc = () => {
  const [deltaY, scrollMode] = useDeltaY();

  return (
    <>
      <h1> deltaY: {deltaY} </h1>
      {scrollMode ? (
        <h1> scrollMode: active </h1>
      ) : (
        <h1> scrollMode: inActive </h1>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```